# Objective C: Using UIImage for Stroking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am trying to apply a texture for my brush but i'm really having a hard time figuring how it is done.

Here's the image of my output.

I used an UIImage that just follows the touch on the screen but when i swipe it faster the result is on the right side "W", and on the left side that's the result when i swipe it slow.

[image]

i tried using the `CGContextMoveToPoint` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint` i don't know how apply the texture.

Is it possible to use UIImage for the stroke texture?

Here's my code

```
    UIImage * brushImageTexture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brushImage.png"]; 
    [brushImagetexture drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(touchCurrentPosition.x, touchVurrentPosition.y) blendMode:blendMode alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: Hi @SeongHo, Im facing some problems while drawing as you wanted. I couldn't draw the texture, not even as the one in the image you posted above. I've posted my question in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390079/stroke-a-cgcontext-path-using-an-image-in-coregraphics ,explaining my problem. Think you can sort it out. Can you help me to find out what is wrong in my code? Please help me to draw like a brush using `CoreGraphics`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manually draw the image at each point along the line from the previous point to the current point.

```
CGPoint vector = CGPointMake(currentPosition.x - lastPosition.x, currentPosition.y - lastPosition.y);
CGFloat distance = hypotf(vector.x, vector.y);
vector.x /= distance;
vector.y /= distance;
for (CGFloat i = 0; i < distance; i += 1.0f) {
    CGPoint p = CGPointMake(lastPosition.x + i * vector.x, lastPosition.y + i * vector.y);
    [brushImageTexture drawAtPoint:p blendMode:blendMode alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: just what i needed thanks Sir! you're a great help! tomorrow my deadline of my school project! thanks a lot!